# JSONAPI Active Model Serializer not separating model relationships to it's own object as spec describes

Tags: active-model-serializers, rails-api, json-api

I'm building a rails app off a tutorial I found and am trying to use a JSONAPI Active Model Serializer to generate a response of that format.

In an initializer, I've put:

`ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api`

In my gemfile:

`gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0.rc3'`

I'm expecting two resource level keys, data and relationships as per the json-api specs. However, is not separating out the relationship to its own object. This is my request for /contacts.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "contacts",
      "attributes": {
        "family-name": "La",
        "given-names": "ch",
        "company": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Lorem Inc",
          "phone": "+1 (415) 555-1234",
          "email": "office@lorem.inc",
          "website": "www.lorem.inc",
          "address": "213 Main St. 94063 San Francisco, CA",
          "customer_id": "10001",
          "additional_info": "",
          "created_at": "2017-01-31T05:47:02.024Z",
          "updated_at": "2017-01-31T05:47:02.024Z"
        },
        "title": null,
        "phone": null,
        "email": null,
        "website": null,
        "address": null,
        "customer-id": null,
        "additional-info": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Company is a belong_to for contacts. Here are my serializers.

```
class CompanySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :phone, :email, :website, :address, :customer_id, :additional_info
end

class ContactSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :family_name, :given_names, :company, :title, :phone, :email, :website, :address, :customer_id, :additional_info
end
```

These are my models:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company

  validates :family_name, presence: true
  validates :given_names, presence: true
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Everything else is just default generated code from rails cli. I'm not sure what else I need to add here because it is my understanding the default rails behavior is to generate a response that will show everything in the serializer. I'm assuming that jsonapi adapter should separate that out for me.

What else do I need to do to get the jsonapi adapter working properly?

Comment: I asked for clarification in a (deleted by admin) answer below and the cross-posted issue in AMS https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/2044#issuecomment-276693712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing relationships in my serializer!

Also answered in x post

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/2044